# update image source on multi-able images on button click

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I want to change mutable images on button click

```
<button id="btn1" >Toggle1</button>    `
<button id="switch" >Toggle2</button>

<img class="im1" src="image1_bw.jpg" />
<img class="im1 im2" src="image2_bw.jpg" />
<img class="im2 im3" src="image3_bw.jpg" />
<img class="im4" src="image4_bw.jpg" />`
```

Ive tried this but can only update 1 image

```
$('#buttonswitch').on({ 'click': function() {

         $('#switch').attr('src','../swap/image1_bw_sec.jpg');
     }
});
```

and i want them to switch back when btn1 is click so basically a toggle function

Many thanks in advance

****** UPDATE *********

[codepen](http://codepen.io/daniel152/pen/qdLeeX?editors=101)

Comment: Please put it on fiddle, It is unclear how you wan to to this, you've got 4 images, does it have to be like a gallery image switch or something else

Comment: And one more thing your are assigning the attribute to the button although it should go to the image tag

Comment: ok i hope this makes more sense http://codepen.io/daniel152/pen/qdLeeX?editors=101

Comment: pls accept my answer i believe i solved your problem thx

Answer (score 0):

This could be your solution.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rgmjokh/)

```js
$("#box1").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("switch1");
});
$("#box2").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("switch2");
});
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara4.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.switch1 {
  background: url("http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara3.jpg") no-repeat!important;
  background-size: contain!important;
  width: 200px!important;
  height: 200px!important;
}
#box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/volunteer1.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.switch2 {
  background: url("http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/volunteer2.jpg") no-repeat!important;
  background-size: contain!important;
  width: 200px!important;
  height: 200px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1">

  &nbsp;

</div>

<div id="box2">

  &nbsp;

</div>
```